# Unsure how certain code works

Tags: python

```
Grid = ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]
  print("This is the grid.")
  for i in range(3):
    print("\t".join(Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]))
```

I was looking for a way to create a 2D 3x3 grid in Python and found this. I want to use it but I'm not sure how line 4 actually works, other than "\t".

Help much appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String.join` method combines a collection with a separator defined. In your example, `\t` is a tab. So you will have a tab between the items in the new string.

```
>>> Grid = ["A1","A2","A3","B1","B2","B3","C1","C2","C3"]
>>> for i in range(3):
    print("\t".join(Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]))


A1  A2  A3
B1  B2  B3
C1  C2  C3

>>> for i in range(3):
    print(" --- ".join(Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]))


A1 --- A2 --- A3
B1 --- B2 --- B3
C1 --- C2 --- C3
```

There is a short tutorial [String.join](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) here.

Comment: Downvote?! It makes me doubt about democracy. This is the most accurate and comprehensible answer by now.

Comment: @cezar there will always be haters.. I wonder also why it got downvoted. thanks for your time commenting this

Comment: Maybe one could explain the evaluation of `(i*3):(i*3+3)`, which slices the list in every iteration step: [0:3], [3:6], [6:9]. From the question however it seems the OP doesn't understand the `join` method, so this is a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

lets break it apart:

```
Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]
```

this is using list slicing. Let's make it easier and say i is 0. then this is

```
Grid[0:3]
```

which is the elements of index 0 to 2, so the first three elements of the list. If i is one, its

```
Grid[3:6]
```

elements with index 3 to 5, the center 3 elements.

`"\t"` is the tab character, the `join()` function puts the preceding string between every element of the list in the parameter. So

```
print("\t".join(Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]))
```

prints three consecutive elements of the list separated by tabs, then starts a new line.

including the `for`-loop, the program prints three lines of 3 elements arranged in a 3x3 grid, with `"A1"` in the top left and `"C3"` in the bottom right:

```
A1      A2      A3
B1      B2      B3
C1      C2      C3
```

Answer (score 0):

`Grid` is a list. Square brackets are used to access elements of the list.
If there is a colon `:` in the square brackets this is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-slice-notation) and it is used to access several elements. e.g. `x[1:4]` picks the second to forth element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's break the `for` loop down:

```
for i in range(3):
    print("\t".join(Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]))
```

`i` here just serves the purpose of iterating over the aforementioned list.  Within the `print()` statement in the for loop, the `join()` method concatenates the elements `Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]` with a tab. Since `i` changes its value from `0` to `3` over the iterations of the loop, the referenced slice from the list would be `Grid[0:3]`, `Grid[3:6]`, `Grid[6:9]` respectively. Then it prints the values in each slice, separated by a tab, and a newline afterwards due to the default `end='\n'` from the `print()` statement.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

You have nine elements in the `Grid` list. The `for` loop iterates three times and each time it selects three consecutive elements from the `Grid` and prints them spaced with tabs. In the last line the `Grid[(i*3):(i*3+3)]` part selects three elements. We can select elements from a list using list slicing. Multiple elements in a list can be selected using `list_name[0:3]`. This will selecting the first three elements. Note that the element with index 3 will not be selected. The result of this slicing is a list.

All the elements are then converted to a single string using the `join` function. The join takes in a list or tuple of words and a separator that is so to say planted between consecutive elements of the list.